# Notepad++ CRLF / LF

Tags: notepad++

I need to search through a number of files, to search for lines that end with a LF (\n) only as opposed to a CRLF (\r\n).

How can I perform a search for only the LF and not pick up all the CRLF characters. By performing a search for '\n', it will pick up both.

I am looking to find:
\n

while ignoring:
\r\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regexp search and give the regexp as  [^\r]\n which will ignore \r and match \n

Comment: Note that this picks up the last character on the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

Combining [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706745/regular-expressions-how-to-match-the-character-not-followed-by-a-or-em) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923846/match-and-delete-lf-character-in-notepad-regex), we get:

```
(?!\r)\n
```

You need to select *Regular expression*, not the *Extended* radio button. [According to the documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions):

> **(?!assert)** (negative lookahead)

The **(?!\r)** means that we do not include the not-`\r` in our match, whereas `[^\r]\n` would match the last character on the previous line along with the `\n`.