# Regex to find and fix LF lineEndings to CRLF

Tags: regex, line-endings

Similar/Related to, but not covered by:

- [Regular Expression to match cross platform newline characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331815/regular-expression-to-match-cross-platform-newline-characters)
- [Match (and delete) LF character in Notepad++ regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923846/match-and-delete-lf-character-in-notepad-regex)

---

I mostly work in .NET stack, where we want (almost) all our files to be CRLF.

In my opinion, git should never be editing the contents of a file, so my and my projects' and my colleagues' git settings are `autocrlf=false` (i.e `as-is, as-is`), feel free to have that debate on [some other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git) :)

Occasionally someone will have bad git settings, or in some other way accidentally introduce LFs into some files in the git repo, and I want to grep the whole repository for files with LF line-endings, and then fix them to be CRLFs, on a file-by-file basis (in case there are, e.g. bash files which *should* regrettably be LF).

Every time I need to do this, I can't find the relevant Regex and have to work it out from scratch again.

So this question exists to document the correct regex.

Comment: Dammit, I literally spent 10 minutes checking for duplicates. :( Ahhh ... that doesn't show up in searches because it uses "LineFeed" not "LF". Ah, well, it's more discoverable now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regex to find any `LF` that is not part of a `CRLF`:

`(?<!\r)\n`

Regex to find any `CR` that is not part of a `CRLF`:

`\r(?!\n)`

Thus Regex to find *any* non-`CRLF` lineEnding:

`((?<!\r)\n|\r(?!\n))`

You can simply replace that with `\r\n` to fix them all to be `CRLF`s.

---

This is using the "Negative Lookbehind" functionality:

> `(?<\!a)b` matches a "b" that was not preceded by an "a".

and the "Negative Lookahead" functionality:

> `a(?\!b)` matches an "a" that is not followed by a "b".

Further documentation here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html